# Force LP32 model for structs in 64bit target

Tags: c, x86, 64-bit, abi

I have a header file which defines several classes:

```
struct Foo {
  int a;
  double b;
  long c;
  struct Foo* next;
};
```

A existing dynamic library using this header file was compiled in LP32 model, but exposed functions are under x86-64 call conventions. (For anyone curious about this situation, this is achieved by sources -> wasm32 -> wasmToNative(x86-64 only)).

I would like to use this shared library, but it is difficult to get LP32 representation of Foo and pass it to this library when the host program is compiled with target x86-64.

I was wondering if there is any way to get Foo structure representation in LP32 model in this case.

Comment: Would it not make sense to explain what toolchain you are using?  Appears to be WebAssmbly related, but you make no mention of that.

Comment: The only ILP32 ABI for x86-64 I'm aware of is the [Linux x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).  It needs kernel support to make sure new page allocations have addresses that fit in 32 bits.  If you have 64-bit addresses in your program, assigning them to `Foo::next` will truncate them to 32-bit!!

Comment: Also, your struct needs padding because you you have an 8-byte `double` after a 4-byte `int`.  Put the `int` and `long` members together at the start or end.  Preferably with the `double` first, because it's always going to be 8 bytes regardless of ILP32 vs. LLP64 (standard Windows x64), and the Windows / MSVC struct layout rules care more about relative alignment of members within structs than about absolute alignment and padding at the end.  So you want `{double; struct Foo*; long; int; }` in that order, unless you need them in this order for SIMD copies or something.

Comment: The fact that `double` requires 4-byte alignment under 32-bit and 8-byte alignment under 64-bit means you are in trouble.  You might be able to achieve it with a `#pragma` for packing structures.

Comment: @Clifford I'm using stock clang's wasm32-wasi target + a self-written wasm2native compiler based on Cranelift, which only supports x86-64 binarygen

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've got some working example by using `#define double MyDouble` with ad-hoc pragmas on `MyDouble` simulating LP32 behavior, but pointers are difficult to be hacked by `#define`